# Prometheus Alertmanager Slack Configuration: send_resolved as flexible value

Tags: alert, prometheus, slack

I want to send a resolve notification to slack based on the alert. Therefore I created an annotation ("resolve") for each alert which is supposed to define if a resolved notification should be send or not.

This is how my alerts look:

```
        - alert: JobsFailing
          expr: rate(failed_jobs_submitter{job="my_job"}[10m]) > 0
          for: 5m
          labels:
            severity: slack_critical
            service: my_service
          annotations:
            identifier: 'my_service_jobs_failing'
            description: 'Jobs are failing'
            resolve: true
```

This is my alertmanager.yaml:

```
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
      slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...'
      http_config:
        proxy_url: 'some_proxy'

    templates:
      - /etc/config/notifications.tpl

    route:
      receiver: 'default-receiver'
      group_wait: 5s
      group_interval: 1m
      repeat_interval: 6h
      routes:
      - receiver: slack_critical
        match:
          severity: slack_critical

    receivers:
    - name: default-receiver

    - name: slack_critical
      slack_configs:
      - channel: '#alert_channel'
        username: "Alert"
        icon_emoji: ":monkey:"
        send_resolved: {{ .Annotations.resolve }}
        title: '{{ template "custom_title" . }}'
        text: '{{ template "custom_slack_message" . }}'
```

I tried using a string instead of a boolean value for .Annotations.resolve

I tried using a template:

```
{{ define resolve_alert }}{{ if eq .Annotations.resolve "true"}}{{ else }}{{ if eq .Annotations.resolve "false" }}{{ end }}
```

and

```
send_resolved: {{ template resolve_alert . }}
```

I tried if-clauses:

```
{{ if eq .Annotations.resolve true }}send_resolved: true{{else}}send_resolved: false{{end}}
```

```
send_resolved: {{ if or .Annotations.resolve | default false }}
```

I expect the slack configuration to pick up the value .Annotations.resolve and to send a resolved message to slack according to the value defined in the alert. What I get when using .Annotations.resolve:

```
level=error ts=2019-10-01T09:08:12.284Z caller=coordinator.go:124 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file failed" file=/etc/config/alertmanager.yml err="yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 28: cannot unmarshal !!map into bool"
```

What I get when using a template:

```
level=error ts=2019-09-30T14:39:29.294Z caller=coordinator.go:124 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file failed" file=/etc/config/alertmanager.yml err="yaml: line 27: did not find expected key"
```

Any input much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

`send_resolved` is a boolean, not a templatable string. What you want is a label, and when have one route that goes to one receiver and another route that goes to another that each have a different boolean value.

It is not possible to route alerts based on annotations, only labels.

Comment: Using a label does not solve it either, the error stay the same: `cannot unmarshal !!map into bool` if I use `{{ .Labels.resolved }}` or `did not find expected key` if I use an if-clause: `{{ if .Labels.resolve == "test" }}true{{else}}false{{end}}`

Comment: I also tried defining an additional route+receiver to achieve a different `send_resolved`, but that did not work out either...